# How to combine JSON values in the response using Java

Tags: java, json

I am currently working on a school project. We have a series of response templates in JSON format that will take values from the request and then return it accordingly in the response when run in postman.

e.g
Request:
{
"Application_id":123456
}

Response:
{ "Application_id: 123456, TIMESTAMP: 20220501}

I am able to get these values in the response but the issue I am running accross now is figuring out how to combine 2 values in the request into one like so:

Request:
{
"Application_id":123456
"user_id_first_six": 456789
"user_id_last_four": 1234
}

Expected Response:
{ "Application_id: 123456, TIMESTAMP: 20220501, combined_id:456789****1234}

what I have tried is to put combined_id : "user_id_first_six"+******+"user_id_last_four" but this doesnt work.

Apologies if I cant be more specific as there are portions that I have left out due to confidentiality issues.

Comment: Can you add the method processing the request at least?

Comment: It seems like you are processing userid-six and userid_four as numbers. Try processing them as String and then try append or concat operation on the combined_id.

Comment: Do you mind sharing some code to show how you are handling the json

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this in Java would be to use `JSONObject`. In your Request-Handler, add two parameters of Type `JSONObject` and then merge them:

```
jsonObj.putAll(jsonObj1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the guidance. I basically did what Knu8 suggested and extracted the values using Matcher+Regex `(<(.*)>)(\W*)(<(.*)>)` and converted them to strings and then used StringBuilder to append all the components together.